# Cartthrob remove product from cart if purchased

Tags: cartthrob, ee

I'm new to cartthrob and want to know how can a product be automatically deleted if that product has been purchased from current logged in user.
Let's see it as a scenario
I'm logged out and I add that product into cart and while checkout I get asked to login and After I login that product gets added to cart even if I've already purchased that product to cart....so please tell me how can I remove that product automatically in Expressionengine cartthrob?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to create an extension on the `cartthrob_add_to_cart_start` hook. This hook runs right before the process of adding an item to the cart so you can check if the member has purchased said product and then apply the `end_script` value and stop execution to meet your needs

Comment: Can you explain a bit more I mean where can I find this hook? Is it in Cartthrob addon file?

Comment: Yeah, it's within the CartThrob Add-on. There are 2 calls to it, the Tag and Action. If you're using the add_to_cart_form tag already, you'll want the Action one located at `cartthrob/src/Actions/AddToCartAction.php`